# Wrong output with for loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, computer-science

This is a simple program i wrote using `for` loop

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        int high=10;

        for( int low =0; low <=high; low++){

            for (int mid=0; mid<=high; mid++)
            {
                System.out.print(mid);

            }
            System.out.println();    
        }
    }
}
```

But I want the output to look like

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

etc...

10
```

Instead my output looks like this `012345678910012345678910012345678910012345678910012345678910012345678910012345678910012345678910012345678910012345678910012345678910`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Set `mid=low` in the second loop and you are also missing the opening `{` for the same loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.print(mid + " ");
```

and

```
System.out.println(" ");
```

Should fix you up.

**EDIT:** Oh ... well, that and:

```
for (int mid = low; mid<=high; mid++)
```

Comment: From the last System.out.[println](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()), you can omit the empty string like he did in his code. It will do essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

You're not printing out any spaces.

```
System.out.print(mid + " ");
```

edit:

In addition, you're starting `mid` at `0` every time through the inner loop rather than starting it at `low`.

Comment: Thats not the answer he wants... His numbers keep coming out like 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 each time.  He wants it to start one number higher each iteration.  He has a logic error I just havent been able to work it out.

Comment: This is what i got after the mid+" " 0 
1
 
2

3

4
 ect

Comment: Well, it's one of the problems he's getting. Should be fixed now

Answer (score 1):

You may want to concatenate a space to your System.out call.

```
System.out.print( mid + " " );
```

Answer (score 1):

Set mid = low in the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

You want to set mid = low, and print spaces as others have noted:

```
int high=10;

for( int low =0; low <=high; low++)
    for (int mid=low; mid<=high; mid++)
    {
        System.out.print("%d ", mid);

    }
    System.out.println();
 }
```

Edit: removed the spurious \n.

Answer (score 1):

Following code will do

```
int high = 10;
    for (int low = 1; low <= high; low++) {
        for (int mid = low; mid <= high; mid++) {
            System.out.print(mid + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this gets you what you want :

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

    int high=10;

    for( int low =0; low <=high; low++)
    {
        for (int mid=low; mid<=high; mid++) //start from low not 0
        {
            System.out.print(mid+" ");

        }
        System.out.println();

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i guess i forgot to have a do loop nested under the first do loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

    int high=10;

    for( int low =0; low<=high; low++) {

        for (int mid=low; mid<=high; mid++) {
            System.out.print(mid + " " );

        }

        System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```